# Background Audio and Cordova 1.7

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to have streaming audio play in the background for an app im developing using Cordova 1.7 (PhoneGap) for iOS. I followed the guide on Joel Dare's website and got the streaming up and running, but his technique for background play doesn't work, which I am assuming is because he is using an older version of PhoneGap as an example. Can someone provide a way to accomplish this using 1.7?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the audio session category to playback?